# Why do properties dissapear from Windows forms designer when extending ActiveX control?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, activex

I'm using PDF-XChange Viewer ActiveX SDK to implement a PDF viewer in my application. The ActiveX object is loaded into the Visual Studio toolbox as can be seen here:

[image: asd]

What you can see here is also the original PDF-XChange Viewer in the bottom and in the top the extended control with a lot less properties available:

[image: asd]

Definition of the extension:

[image]

The rest of the code is custom methods, properties, events and a few overrides.

It seems that the extended control not only lacks the properties, but also doesn't respect them if I set them in code (Dock and Anchor for example - regardless of the fact that both are available in the base control).

Any idea why this happens and how to fix it?

Comment: What do you mean by "extended control"? Are they two different versions?

Comment: Same as if I was extending a built in Windows forms control, for example `public class MyTextBox : System.Windows.Forms.TextBox { }`. The code is in the last screenshot.

Comment: Are the missing properties `protected`?

Comment: `AxCoPDFXCview` implements `AxHost` (abstract class) which extends `Control` and implements `ISupportInitialize`/`ICustomTypeDescriptor`, so they're `public` and inherited from `Control`, but none of them are showing.

Comment: Have you seen http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7883/Importing-and-Extending-ActiveX-Controls-in-NET ? _"When we try to [subclass the control] in this way, we run into lots of problems mainly due to the fact that the .NET generated class does not expose its members in a level that its subclass can access. The reason is probably that Visual Studio .NET expects you to import and use an existing ActiveX control, but not extend an ActiveX control. Fortunately, Visual Studio .NET 2003 provides a utility called AxImp.exe that supports ActiveX importing and source code generation._"

Comment: I have now. Given that I'm not in control of the implementation of `AxCoPDFXCview` (the class that subclasses `AxHost` - equivalent to `AxCalendar` in the CodeProject) I assume I can't really make the necessary changes for my subclass to work?